# Error in Sending Form file with form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to submit form using AJAX that contains CSV File. So the idea is sending the form using ajax, process it in different file by generating a table and call back the processed table back into the page.

What i Have is this,

```
<form id="uploadXls" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="uploaderFile" type="file" class="file"><br/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> SHOW FILE CONTENT</button>
</form>
```

and the JavaScript is,

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../content/maindiv_content/drawing/divpages/process_xls_file.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $("#showFileContentTable").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

and im getting this kind of error in firebug,

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.
http://infserver/WeltesTankage/dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js line 4 > eval
Line 14
```

What am i doing wrong here ? Please help me

Comment: `this` refers to your button and not the form as that is where you are catching the click event.

Comment: With me I accidentally gave my form the same ID as another element and the AJAX request was trying to use the other element which was not a form object.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't pass the files into the constructor, but use append, like:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
data:  formData
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`. well - ..

Comment: And how do I put the other data from form?

Answer (score 45):

You can use this approach too.

```
var form = $('form').get(0);
```

this code returns a jQuery object(`$('form')`) and pass a HTML element to FormData (`get(0)`).

then in ajax request: `data: new FormData(form),`

Comment: This needs more upvotes! Works perfectly and is super easy to understand! Thanks.

Comment: yes ;) and you can reset all the form field, by adding this to success function: `$('#FormID')[0].reset();` this might help someone too :)

Comment: Great solution, saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

You pass `this` to the `FormData` constructor. In this context, `this` is the button clicked, identified in the error message as a `HTMLFormElement`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) the `FormData` constructor expects a `form` element. So you have to change your code accordingly:

```
 var form = $("#uploadXls");

 $ajax({
     ...
     data: new FormData(form),
     ....
 });
```

Comment: still having an error : ReferenceError: formData is not defined
http://infserver/WeltesTankage/dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js line 4 > eval
Line 15

Comment: @KonzMama Sorry, a typo. FormData should have a capital F of course

Comment: still having an error, this is my code snippet 
`var form = $("#uploadXls");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                data: new FormData(form),
                url: '../../content/maindiv_content/drawing/divpages/process_xls_file.php',`

Answer (score 3):

may be this page help you..:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" id="fileinfo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    file <input type="file" name="slug"><br>
     <input type="button" id="uploadBTN" value="Stash the file!"></input>
  </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('#uploadBTN').on('click', function()
      { 
        var form = $('form').get(0); 
        console.log(form);
        var fd = new FormData(form);
        fd.append('user_id',4);
        fd.append('user_media_category_id',1);
        //console.log(fd);
        fd.append("user_", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/yii2/voila/project/api/web/v1/user-media/new',  
            type: 'POST',
            data: fd,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this form, it works for me without problems,
Greetings, I hope I can help you.

//normalize form

```
var formulario = new FormData($('#form_img').get(0));    
    formulario.append('file', $('#customFile')[0].files[0]);

//AND add in Ajax call

data:formulario
```