# jQuery - DataTables upload file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the plugin `datatable` to show a list of users. In this list I need to be able to upload new files.

I am trying to use ajax to try to send data to php. If I send value there is not problem my php script works however, I cannot get the data from the files.

In order to upload the files I am using the same script that I have written for another project which is working fine, so I think here the problem is `DataTable` that do not recognise my form data.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mau1xuu6/10/)

JS

```
$('#example .fileinput-upload-button').on('click', function(event) {

  var td = $(this).closest("td");
  var parentTD = td.parent();

  var form = $(this).closest("form");
var url = "example/upload.php?type=photo"
  var data = new FormData(form);
  alert(form);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {

      alert(data);
    }
  });
```

PHP

```
$type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "type");


$target_dir_header = $includesDir . "dashboard/resources/header_pic/";
$dataHeader = $_FILES['input7'];
$dataHeader_ext = explode('/', $dataHeader['type']);
$imageFileType_header = $dataHeader_ext[1];
$target_file_header = $target_dir_header . basename("header" . $imageFileType_header);


echo $type . " - " . $imageFileType_header;
```

Comment: There is no `form` tag in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes there is .. just before the input

Comment: You're right, sorry. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872872/error-in-sending-form-file-with-form-using-ajax). Try   `var data = new FormData();  data.append('file', $('input[type=file]', form)[0].files[0]);` instead.

Comment: thanks, I have tried but still I cannot get the file. If I `var_dump($path_)` I get ` ["basename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["filename"]=>
  string(0) ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JQuery code to:

```
var td = $(this).closest("td");
var parentTD = td.parent();

var url = "example/upload.php?type=photo"
var form = $(this).closest("form").get(0);

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: new FormData(form),
   mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   dataType: "html",
   processData: false,
   success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
   }

});
```

Your question explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872872/error-in-sending-form-file-with-form-using-ajax)

Comment: Thank you.. this is working however, the php is receiving just the data from the first row. If I select a picture on other rows the data received is always from the first row in table

Comment: @SNos, Use `$(this).closest("form").get(0)` instead of `$('form').get(0)`.