# JavaScript, Ajax Form Submit - error on first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I know this basic subject has been broached many times, and I have used code that has been posted from here in my own application. However, I have run into an error I just cannot resolve, and it is making me crazy. I have a form with two hidden controls (which have not been an issue in other forms), a file control, some standard input controls and a textarea ... (a sample of the form is below). When I use JavaScript (and Ajax) to try to submit it, I am getting an error that I cannot resolve:

TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Form:

```
<form class='form form-horizontal' method='post' action='' name='attachment_form' id='attachment_form'>
  <input value=1 name='event_link3' id='event_link3' hidden />
  <input value=9683 name='contributor_link3' id='contributor_link3' hidden />
  <div class='row'>
     <!-- file upload option -->
     <div class='col-lg-5 col-11'>
        <div class='form-group file-upload'>
           <label>Select File to Upload:</label><br />
           <input type='file' class='form-control' id='attachment_file' 
                                    name='attachment_file' accept='.pdf, .mp4, .mov, .avi, .f4v' 
                                    data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'
                                    title='File to be uploaded should be &#39;standard&#39; video or pdf format'
                             />
        </div> <!-- / form-group -->
     </div> <!-- // col-5 -->
     <div class='col-1'>            <a name='attachment_clear'
                             onclick='attachment_clear()'
                             class='btn btn-primary btn-md clearButton'
                             data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Clear Selection'
                             style='margin-left: -12px !important; margin-top: 40px !important;'>
                             <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
     </div> <!-- // col-1 -->
     <div class='col-lg-6 col-12'>
        <label>Web Link/URL:</label><br />
        <input type='url' class='form-control'
                                 id='web_url' name='web_url' 
                                 data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'
                                 title='Web address must include http:// or https:// to be valid'
                          />
     </div> <!-- // col-6 -->
  </div> <!-- // row -->
  <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-lg-6 col-12'>
        <label>Short Description:</label>
        <input class='form-control' name='short_description' id='short_description'
                                 data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'
                                 title='A short description of the file (displayed for link)' required/>
     <p class='help-block'><b>Short Description is Required</b> -- the text will be used
                       to display as text for the file link.</p>
     </div> <!-- // col-6-->
     <div class='col-lg-6 col-12'>
        <label>File Description:</label>
        <textarea class='form-control' name='description' id='description' rows=5 required></textarea>
        <p class='help-block'><b>Description is Required</b> -- Describe the file or link in as much
                          detail as you need ... you can also format this to some extent (see toolbar)</p>
     </div> <!-- // col-12-->
  </div> <!-- // row -->
  <button id='attachment_submit' name='attachment_submit' class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 10px;'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i>&nbsp;Upload Attachment</button>
</form>
```

The Javascript code to deal with the form is based on code I have pulled here on StackOverflow, and has been working successfully in other places. I cannot see what is different or wrong with this ...

```
$("#attachment_form").submit(function(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault();

     // first thing, clear out the message div used for this (if there's anything there):
     document.getElementById("attachment_message").innerHTML = "";

     // validation:
     var filename_check = document.getElementById( "attachment_file" ).value;
     var web_url_check  = document.getElementById( "web_url" ).value;
     if ( filename_check == "" && web_url_check == "" )
     {
        alert( "You must either select a file to upload or enter a web address ..." );
        return;
     }
     // on the flip side:
     if ( filename_check != "" && web_url_check != "" )
     {
        alert( "You must either select a either file to upload or a web address, not both ..." );
        return;
     }

     // get value from TinyMCE
     var description  = tinymce.get('description').getContent();
     // make sure it's in the textarea by the same name
     document.getElementById( "description" ).value = description;


     // this has always worked in the past, but having issues:
     var formData = new FormData(this);
 // this is where the error occurs when I open the web console of my browser
```

I am hoping someone has experience with this and can tell me what the error is, as I am completely stumped at this point. (I have checked "this.id" in an alert to be sure I am using the correct form ...)

Comment: From the error it looks like the `this` doesn't point to the right place, have you tried to replace it with the actual form div? `var formData = new FormData($("#attachment_form"));`

Comment: Yes. I have tried a lot of different variations. I just tried this and I get the exact same error.

Comment: From the code above you have a misspell, on line 16 `<div class=col-1'>` you forgot the single quote there: `<div class='col-1'>` not sure if this might solve the issue

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that. But it doesn't seem to have resolved anything (refreshed the page and so on ...). (That's an excellent catch, though ...)

Comment: `$("#attachment_form")` is not a form element; it is a jQuery object. Try passing `$("#attachment_form")[0]`. I'd do `console.log($("#attachment_form")[0])` to ensure it's a `form` element though; it could be you have two elements with the same id.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/977306/  at this fiddle it looks like everything is working as expected, have you saw this question and tried the answers? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28872872/8727608

Comment: If I do it on the first line of the javascript code I get "TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function". If I do it in the code below where I try to get the formData, I get the same error.

Comment: Art3mix -- I tried the examples there and it is still returning the same error.

Comment: Can you `console.log(this)` above the new FormData line and add it to the question?

Comment: Art3mix -- the output for that is huge ... how much do you want to see?

Comment: just the first line before you open it

Comment: Figured out, see "answer" ... d'oh. Feeling rather sheepish this morning.

Comment: Happened to everyone, make sure to check your logs next time, saves so much time

Answer (score 0):

The FormData call probably expects a DOM element and not a jQuery element. Try passing this[0] or this.get() to get the Html element of the form.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this particular response. I have tried many variations of passing the form ... Do you mean:
`code`
var formData = new FormData(this[0]);
`code`? If so I get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my problem *(thanks to the suggestion to look at the output log by Art3mix above)*. The issue was that I had a surrounding div tag that was *also* called "attachment_form" (I have a collapsible (bootstrap 4) div that is opened with a button, and I didn't even think about the fact that I had named the form the same as the div). By changing that (and references to it) to "attachment_window" instead, that resolve the whole thing. Wow. Thanks for the suggestion to look at the console output log. I seldom, if ever, look at that.