# I am trying to call an API when submitting a form using Fetch() but facing an error

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Problem is

> "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input" 
>  & CORB(cross-origin read blocking).

My code is

```js
handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch('http://api.valios.net/user/signup',
    {
       method:'POST',
       mode:'no-cors',
       headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
        body: data,
    })
    .then(response => response.json()) //handle json response
    .then(responseJson => {
      console.log(responseJson);
    });
}
```

Comment: First, you shoudl declare it like `function handleSubmit(event)`. Second, you have misused `FormData`, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872952/4636715) for the correct usage. Fix those problems and edit your quesion first, otherwise your question would not be reproduced properly.

Answer (score 0):

You put no-cors and a header of Cross origin you can change your code as follows

```
handleSubmit(event){
event.preventDefault();
const data = new FormData(event.target);
fetch('http://api.valios.net/user/signup',
{
   method:'POST',
   mode:'cors',
   headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
    body: data,
})
  .then(response => response.json()) //handle json response
  .then(responseJson => {
    console.log(responseJson);
  });
}
```

regards