# Laravel controller can't save files from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

So I have problems with uploading my image files to controller via ajax. My partner suppose to have many images. I successfully sent my images to controller via ajax, but the files cannot be store to database for some reason. I tried to send back the files request back to console log and see only empty objects. Any solution, guys?

This is my form:

```
<form 
  id="kkpn-partnerImg-form"
  method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
      
 >
  <input 
    id="kkpn-upload-file" 
    type="file" 
    name="partnerImg[]"
    multiple
    accept="image/*"
    data-url="{{ route('partners.partner_upload_images.store', $partner->id) }}"
    hidden
  >
    <button
      class="btn btn-success" 
      id="kkpn-upload-btn"
     >
       Upload your images
    </button>
</form>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#kkpn-upload-btn').on('click', openDialog)

  function openDialog(){
    document.getElementById('kkpn-upload-file').click();
  }

  $('#kkpn-partnerImg-form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    if ($('#kkpn-upload-file').get(0).files.length != 0) {
      var uploadUrl = $('#kkpn-upload-file').data('url');

      formData.append(
        '_token',
        $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      )

      for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
      }
      
      $.ajax(
        {
          url: uploadUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          cache:false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,

          success: function(response){
            console.log(response.data)
          },
          error: function(error){
            console.log('Error Occured!')
          }
        }
      )
    }

  })

  $('#kkpn-upload-file').on('change', function(){
    $('#kkpn-partnerImg-form').submit()
  })

})
```

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $partner = Partner::where('id', $id)->first();

    foreach($request->file('partnerImg') as $fileImg){
      $partnerImg = new PartnerImg;
      $partnerImg->img_path = $fileImg->store('partners');
      $partnerImg->partner()->associate($partner);
      $partnerImg->save();  
    }
    
    return response()->json([
      'data' => $request->file('partnerImg')
    ]); 
    
  }
```

So it didn't give me any errors or anything, it just can't store the file and when i return my request with files, it gave me empty objects. If any one know how to solve this, please help!

And this is what I get after successfully response of ajax:
[image]

Comment: try => `var_dump($request->all())` and see what coming in the request.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I did and it displays empty space on the top of the page.

Comment: okay thats weird => are you sure that function is getting called at all ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Sending Form file with form using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872872/error-in-sending-form-file-with-form-using-ajax)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes, I test it many time in controller with condition and I return it back to ajax. It did return correct numbers of object files. One more things if i use $_FILES i can see the the information of files such type, name, ... but i don't know how to store it to database.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've already tried from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872872/error-in-sending-form-file-with-form-using-ajax, it's not working!

Comment: I can't see the **CSRF** in your form!!

Comment: I sent it with formdata in javascript @Moayad.AlMoghrabi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I delete everything and redo again! It works! Sorry guys! But thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As you're uploading an array of files, have you attempted accessing them with

```
foreach($request->file('partnerImg[]') as $fileImg) {
```

in your controller?

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-upload-multiple-files-using-ajax-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

first problem i have seen is that you are not passing the $id parameter on ajax

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $partner = Partner::find($id); //change to this!

    foreach($request->file('partnerImg[]') as $fileImg){
      $partnerImg = new PartnerImg;
      $partnerImg->img_path = $fileImg->store('partners');
      $partnerImg->partner()->associate($partner);
      $partnerImg->save();  
    }
    
    return response()->json([
      'data' => $request->file('partnerImg[]')
    ]); 
    
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but my url is like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/partners/2/partner_upload_images/store